# How to match two arrays based on closest values +/-

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula for column L, but I am having trouble. I have two columns of data that I'm trying to compare (J & K), and I want to find the closest value in column J (+/-) to all the values in column K, and reference which value is closest from column J, and put it in column L. It would result in something like the cells below. All the examples I have looked at just compare to one single cell, like

`{=INDEX(E3:E11,MATCH(MIN(ABS(E3:E11-I3)),ABS(E3:E11-I3),0)))}`

but I'm looking at closest values for two arrays/columns of data.

[image: Example]

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with your formula. Are you entering it as an array formula?

Comment: I've tried using formulas as an array but it only works for the first cell.

Comment: You may be looking for HLOOKUP and its friends https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-hlookup-function

Comment: Are you using the correct ranges, and locking the references? Your formula refers to E and I, your screenshot to J and K.

Comment: "I've tried using formulas as an array "... as a single array, or an array per cell? Did you select cells L2:L6, press F2, enter the formula and hit ctrl+shift+enter? Or did you enter the formula in L2, hith ctrl+shift+enter and then drag L2 down to L6? I would think for your example you would want the latter with this formula: `{=INDEX(J$3:J$11,MATCH(MIN(ABS(J$3:J$11-K3)),ABS(J$3:J$11-K3),0)))}`

Comment: Sorry, that was just an example from a website I tried to find the solution from: https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-find-closest-match/   I've tried to apply the formula to my cells, but it hasn't been working

Comment: Also I should add that the arrays can be of any length

Comment: What have you actually tried **on your own** worksheet?  The formula you posted doesn't refer to any of the cells you show in your screenshot.

Comment: I've tried the following '{=INDEX(J2:J1048576,MATCH(MIN(ABS(J2:J1048576-K2)),ABS(J2:J1048576-K2),0))}'

Comment: Can I rely on Column J being ordered ascending?

Comment: @WolfgangJacques Yes

Comment: OK - but not needed in my solution below :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array Formula in L2:

```
{=OFFSET($J$1,MATCH(MIN(ABS(K2-$J$2:$J$100)),ABS(K2-$J$2:$J$100),0),0)}
```

Take $100 or any other number. Enter by hitting Ctrl+Alt+Enter. Copy down as individual array formulae, i.e. just drag down the formula.

What I do is:

`ABS(K2-$J$2:$J$100)` calculate the absolute differences for each value (need not be sorted!)

`MIN(ABS(K2-$J$2:$J$100))` Take the smallest of these values - that's the line you have to go for!

`MATCH(MIN(ABS(K2-$J$2:$J$100));ABS(K2-$J$2:$J$100);0)` Find the position of the smallest value within all values.

`OFFSET($J$1; <position>  ;0)` From J1, take the cell `<position>` rows down and `0` columns across - Bingo!

Comment: OK, @Dan's formula matches mine, as I now found - his example would be `INDEX(J$2:J$100,MATCH(MIN(ABS(J$2:J$100-K2)),ABS(J$2:J$100-K2),0))`in my sheet. Just a difference in taste, I would say.